React animated animation causes app crashes
I'm learning how to code in react native using Expo by making an old project found online, for now I need to make a square to move like that : blog.swmansion.com/reanimated-2-the-game-9402622c1fe5
It's like a tinder app animation, I tried to reach it by using reanimated and gesture handler but when I press the square on expo go on android the app crashes.
Here is the link of the old project : https://github.com/wojtus7/reanimated-story-cards/blob/iteration-1/Card.js (I m at iteration 1)
Here is my code :
App.js
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {GestureHandlerRootView} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

import Card from './components/Card';
import useGeneratedCards from './components/useGeneratedCards';

export default function AnimatedStyleUpdateExample() {
    const {getCardByIndex} = useGeneratedCards();
    const [currentCard, setCurrentCard] = useState(getCardByIndex(0));

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.wrapper}>
            <Card
                onChooseLeftAnswer={() => null}
                onChooseRightAnswer={() => null}
                leftText={currentCard.leftText}
                rightText={currentCard.rightText}
                image={currentCard.image}
                backgroundColor={currentCard.background}
            />
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});

Card.js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
    useSharedValue,
    useAnimatedStyle,
    withSpring,
    interpolate,
    Extrapolate,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {Gesture, GestureDetector} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Card = ({
                  onChooseLeftAnswer,
                  onChooseRightAnswer,
                  leftText,
                  rightText,
                  image,
                  backgroundColor,
              }) => {
    const x = useSharedValue(0);
    const y = useSharedValue(0);

    const cardSpringConfig = {
        damping: 100,
        stiffness: 90,
        mass: 0.5,
    };

    const gestureHandler = Gesture.Pan()
        .onStart((event, context) => {
            context.startX = x.value;
            context.startY = y.value;
        })
        .onUpdate((event, context) => {
            x.value = context.startX + event.translationX;
            y.value = context.startY + event.translationY;
        })
        .onEnd(() => {
            if (x.value < -100) {
                onChooseLeftAnswer();
            } else if (x.value > 100) {
                onChooseRightAnswer();
            }
            x.value = withSpring(0, cardSpringConfig);
            y.value = withSpring(0, cardSpringConfig);
        });

    const animatedMovableCard = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            transform: [
                {
                    rotateZ: `${interpolate(
                        x.value,
                        [-50, 50],
                        [-0.05, 0.05],
                        Extrapolate.EXTEND,
                    )}rad`,
                },
                {translateX: x.value},
                {translateY: y.value},
            ],
        };
    });

    return (
        <View style={styles.cardWrapper}>
            <GestureDetector gesture={gestureHandler}>
                <Animated.View
                    style={[animatedMovableCard, styles.wrapper, {backgroundColor}]}
                />
            </GestureDetector>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        height: 240,
        width: 240,
        borderRadius: 35,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    cardWrapper: {
        height: 240,
    },
});

export default Card;


I tried what Copilot suggested me (check if dependencies where installed, check babel.config.js, use GestureHandlerRootView) but nothing worked.
Edit : It seems that the problem is due to the gestureHandler, on web the console says " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startX')" when I slide the square. I tried a more simple animation (if double tap, the square's size increases) and it work, so reanimated is not the problem imo of course.
